# Looking if there are two spaces in a string with string::find, a bug in this code?

Tags: c++, string

I am reading the [string manipulations in C++](https://www.mochima.com/tutorials/strings.html). There the author presented a piece of code which is testing if there are two spaces in a string,

```
string text;
getline (cin, text);

string::size_type position = text.find (' ');
if (position != string::npos)
{
    if  (text.find (' ', position+1) != string::npos)
    {
       cout << "Contains at least two spaces!" << endl;
    }else
    {
       cout << "Contains less than two spaces!" << endl;
    }
}else
{
  cout << "Contains no spaces!" << endl;
}
```

The author states that there is a bug in the above code. But I couldn't see it, the code looks fine for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only issue I can see is if the first space is the last character of the string...

Comment: From the web page: _The requirement for this optional parameter is that it must indicate a valid position within the string, which means that the value must be between 0 and length−1_. Is `position+1` guaranteed to be in that range?

Comment: yes, the author states that. But `std::string::find` actually accepts number greater than the string length, as said [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: @Barmar The author is wrong, there's no such requirement. And I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: (Arguably) the bug in the code is that it doesn't test `cin` after `getline()`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of that web site is wrong, there's no bug in the program.

He thinks there's a requirement that the optional argument to `find` must be between 0 and `length-1`. If that were the case, then the program would fail if the first space is the last character of the string, because `position` will be `length-1`, and therefore `position+1` will be `length`, which is outside that range.

But actually, if the `position` argument is too high, it just returns `string::npos`. So there's no problem.

Comment: Where did you get this requirement from? `basic_string::find` will return `npos` if the start position argument is greater than the length of the string.

Comment: I got it from the web page he linked to. If it's not really a requirement (which it appears it isn't) then the author was mistaken in saying that there's a bug in the program.

Comment: I just tested, `find` can take arguments that are greater than `length-1`. And for `text="a "`(one space), it actually outputs "Contains less than two spaces!"; and for `text="a  "`(two spaces), it outputs "Contains at least two spaces!"`.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks. I've corrected my answer to explain the bug that the author _thinks_ he has, based on his misunderstanding of the spec.

Comment: From the C++03 standard, *Returns: `xpos` if the function can determine such a value for `xpos`. Otherwise, returns `npos`.* Where `xpos` is the position of the search term, if present, and there is no other stated requirement that the `pos` argument be within any range.